# AVAudio session interruption

Tags: swift, swift4, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession, nsnotifications

Trying to handle audio interruption in my project.

**This code used to work in swift 4.**

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleInterruption(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVAudioSessionInterruption, object: nil)
```

**Since updating to Swift 4.2 it gave me suggestion to change to**

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleInterruption(_:)), name: Notification.Name.AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification, object: nil)
```

After changing to the suggested fix, I am getting Error:
**Type 'Notification.Name' (aka 'NSNotification.Name') has no member 'AVAudioSession'**

Any help would be appreciated.

**The Documents used:**

```
func setupNotifications() {
let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleInterruption), name: .AVAudioSessionInterruption, object: nil)
```

}

But the document isn't updated for swift 4.2.

Answer (score 8):

There are bugs in Xcode migrator tool. The correct fix is,

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleInterruption(_:)), name: AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification, object: nil)
```

Comment: Do we need to remove the observer for this?